# is it possible to "clone" a table variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table variable with about 20 columns. I'd like to essentially reuse a single table variable structure for 2 different result sets. The 2 result sets should be represented in different table variables so I can't reuse a single table variable. Therefore, I was wondering if there was a way to clone a single table variable for reuse.  For example, something like this:

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar1 TABLE(
   Col1 INT,
   Col2 INT
}

DECLARE @MyTableVar2 TABLE = @MyTableVar1
```

I'd like to avoid creating duplicate SQL if I can reuse existing SQL.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `DECLARE @MyTableVar2 TABLE = @MyTableVar1`?

Comment: hi tripp.  thanks I made a typo and updated my code sample.

Comment: why cant you use the same table variable name for both result sets i dont get it

Comment: Why don't you add a column called "ResultSetID" and for the first set use 1 and the second set use 2? If you have 5 result sets you'll have 5 table variables? If you have 200?

Answer (score 4):

That is not possible, use temp table instead

```
if object_id('tempdb..#MyTempTable1') is not null drop table #MyTempTable1
Create TABLE #MyTempTable1 (
   Col1 INT,
   Col2 INT
)

if object_id('tempdb..#MyTempTable2') is not null drop table #MyTempTable2
select * into #MyTempTable2 from #MyTempTable1
```

update :

As suggested by Eric in comment, if you are looking for just table schema and not the data inside the first table then

```
select * into #MyTempTable2 from #MyTempTable1 where 1 = 0
```

Comment: @user9393635 - Nope, only if you use `##` it is global.

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, but that last line should have a WHERE 1=2 condition if all you want to copy is the table schema. As written, it's going to populate the second table.

Comment: @EricBrandt - fair comment, will add it in answer

Answer (score 2):

You can create a user-defined table type which is typically meant for using table valued parameters for stored procedures. Once the type is created, you can use it as a type to declare any number of table variables just like built-in types. This comes closest to you requirement.

Ex:

```
CREATE TYPE MyTableType AS TABLE   
( COL1 int  
, COL2 int )

DECLARE @MyTableVar1 AS MyTableType
DECLARE @MyTableVar2 AS MyTableType
```

A few things to note with this solution

1. MyTableType becomes a database level type. It is not local to a specific stored procedure.
2. If you have to ever change the definition of the table, then you have to drop the code/sprocs using the TVP type, then recreate the table type with new definition and related sprocs. Typically this is a non-issue as the code and the type are created/recreated together.

Comment: While I like this answer and have upvoted it, I would probably only create data types for very general purposes. If it's a table type only used in a single procedure multiple times, I would suggest using the temp table approach in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a temp table and select into... they perform better since their statistics are better.

```
create table #myTable(
   Col1 INT null,
   Col2 INT null
}

...

select * 
into #myTableTwo
from #myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create one table variable and add type column in the table and use the type column in your queries to filter the data.

By this you are using one table to hold more than one type of data.
Hope this helps.

```
declare @myTable table(
   Col1 INT null,
   Col2 INT null,
....
  Type INT NULL
}


insert into @myTable(...,type)
select ......,1

insert into @myTable(...,type)
select ......,2

select * from @myTable where type =1 
select * from @myTable where type =2
```